# Why does this Twig code not work?

Tags: views, 10

I've recently upgraded my Drupal 9.5 website to Drupal 10.1. Everything went smoothly except for a Display with Views that contained twig code within one of the fields to rewrite the results.

Prior to the upgrade, this code containing twig within the Views display worked.

```html
<span class="field-content"><span hidden itemprop="dateCreated">{{ created | date('Y-m-d') -}}></span>Published on {{ created | date('F j, Y') }}</span>
```

Can someone tell me with the upgrade to Drupal 10.1.2 using Twig 3.x why this code no longer works? Can Twig 3.x code still be used as I have described it?

Comment: Never mind. Found the answer. Twig value has to read {{ created.value | date('Y-m-d') }} for it work.

Comment: @user189842 Feel free to answer your own question instead of posting another comment. On this site it's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question:

With the upgrade to Drupal 10.1,Twig 3.x treats unix timestamps differently. Instead of using the twig field {{ created }}, use the raw value {{ created__raw }} followed by the piped date format you want to display. Thus :

`{{ created__raw | date('F j, Y') }}`